# Deleting last keystroke in JTextField if invalid

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

Working on my 1st program. I figured out how to identify characters I do not want to be able to be inputted. I would like to know how do delete the last character entered so that from a user perspectvive it will appear as only numbers can be entered.

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    char keyChar = e.getKeyChar();;
    char[] badCharArray = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-`~!@#$%^&*()[]{}<>_+=|\"':;?/ ".toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < badCharArray.length; i++) {
            if (badCharArray[i] == keyChar) {
                System.out.print(badCharArray[i] + " bad\n");
                hourlyWageInput.setBackground(Color.RED);
                } 
            }
        }
```

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: e.Consume() would stop it be being passed to the text field, but then there's no reason to turn it red....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the creation of the JTextField:

```
hourlyWageInput = new JTextField("7.25");
DocumentFilter filter = new UppercaseDocumentFilter();
((AbstractDocument) hourlyWageInput.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(filter);
hourlyWageInput.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
add(hourlyWageInput);
```

Here is my DocumentFilter:

```
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class UppercaseDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

     public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
          String text, javax.swing.text.AttributeSet attr)

          throws BadLocationException {
               fb.insertString(offset, text.replaceAll("\\D", ""), attr);   
     }
}
```

This works, automatically removing all letters and characters from the JTextField. So thank you, this is the best for sure.

However, I was wondering if anyone knows of a place with all of the commands similar to "\D". It took me a while to find the right information.

Also, the code I have now also prevents . from being types which I need as I am working with doubles. Any ideas?

Thanks for all of the help, its amazing how much I have learned today. Been coding 13 hours straight.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is simply to use a JFormattedTextField instead of a JTextField.

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2); // eventually maximum fraction digits

JFormattedTextField fld = new JFormattedTextField(format);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid `keyListener`s in this case.  What happens if the user pastes text into field.  The `keyListener` will not be notified, allowing invalid characters to be inserted.

You're better of using [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) to filter out any invalid characters you don't want.

Take a look at [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information and [DocumentFilter](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for some nice examples

Comment: The key listener does actually detect ctrl + v, however, if he adds a right-click menu, yes, it would fail there, but by default that is not on a JTextField.

Comment: @Alex: this is the better answer by far. 1+. DocumentFilters will allow modification entered data *before* it is displayed, before it is validated.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, I just said that this would fail for a certain case (that he doesnt have); however, 99% of the time mine will still work. No need to downvote it...

Comment: @Alex: You should not condone use of KeyListeners for Swing applications as they really should be avoided. Yes, they're a quick and "easy" solution, but they're too low level -- especially when more robust higher level solutions are available. Again, they fail anything to do with copy-paste, they fail for alternative input devices, they're just wrong in this situation. Period.

Comment: @AlexColeman what about `setText` ?  `KeyListener` will not be notified of this at all?  I agree, the question was about a `KeyListener` implementation, but we should encourage good practices as well, I also feel into the trap of just answering the question and while you're solution works, it is prone to Document mutation exceptions

Comment: As an aside, @David really should use a JTable with custom editors and renderers as has been suggested previously.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help. You guys rule.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set it's text to be the current text, without the character before the caret position

---

```
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent paramKeyEvent) {
        char keyChar = paramKeyEvent.getKeyChar();
        char[] badCharArray = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-`~!@#$%^&*()[]{}<>_+=|\"':;?/ ".toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < badCharArray.length; i++) {
                if (badCharArray[i] == keyChar) {
                    int caret = field.getCaretPosition()-1;
                    System.out.print(badCharArray[i] + " bad\n");
                    field.setText(field.getText().substring(0, caret) + 
                            field.getText().substring(caret+1));
                    field.setCaretPosition(caret);
                    } 
            }
    }
```

Took out the setting it to red, as if you're going to auto-correct it, no point in having that there (maybe set it to show red for one second?)

---

Actually, the only issue with that is that if they hold in an invalid key, it only deletes the last one; the following should work a lot better, and won't shift the caret :P

```
        boolean held = false;
        private int oldCaret = 1;
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(! held) {
                oldCaret=field.getCaretPosition();
                System.out.println(oldCaret);
            }
            held = true;

        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent paramKeyEvent) {
            char keyChar = paramKeyEvent.getKeyChar();
            char[] badCharArray = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-`~!@#$%^&*()[]{}<>_+=|\"':;?/ ".toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < badCharArray.length; i++) {
                if(field.getText().contains(badCharArray[i]+"")) {
                    field.setText(field.getText().replace(badCharArray[i]+"", ""));
                    field.setCaretPosition(oldCaret);
                }
            }

            held=false;
        }
```

Comment: @DavidTunnell: this is not the correct answer, and you do not want to use a KeyListener. The correct and more robust answer is to use a DocumentFilter as per MadProgrammer's answer. It can handle copy and paste as well as other non-keyboard input.

Comment: @DavidTunnell Btw, you need to add in capital characters to that char[], A-Z, not just a-z