# Java TextBox KeyReleased Event to Check isNumeric()

Tags: java, swing, events, textbox, numeric

Im trying to to check whenever a user types a character into textbox if it is a number.  If it is not it should immediately remove it from the textbox.

What happens is I type in the number 1 (or any number or character), and it removes the value from the textbox when it is obviously a number.

Here is the event I am using:

```
private void txtLengthAKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    removeLastChar(txtLengthA); //pass the textbox 
}
```

Here is removeLastChar() method:

```
public static void removeLastChar(JTextField txt)
{
    //Get string from text field
    String str = txt.getText();
    //Make sure length > 0
    if( (str.length()) != 0)
    {
        //Get the last char of the string
        String s = str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length()-1);
        System.out.println(s);   //test debug
        //If not numeric (try/catch Double.parseDouble)
        if(!isNumeric(s));
        {
            //Remove last char from the text box
            str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
            txt.setText(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Check if string is numeric:

```
isNumeric() function:
    public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
    {  
      try  
      {  
        double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
      }  
      catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
      {  
        return false;  
      }  
      return true;  
    }
```

Comment: Please have a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9477354/1057230), answer to this question and the reason why it is closed can give you a good idea about how to go around this situation :-) **KeyEvents** are too low level for Swing, instead use **DocumentFilter** as described in some answers and that link.

Comment: Ahh I was afraid you guys would say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `KeyListeners` to filter or modify `JTextComponets` is only going to end in tears.

You should be using a `DocumentFilter`

Check out [Limit the Characters in the text field using document listner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812844/limit-the-characters-in-the-text-field-using-document-listner/12812935#12812935), [Deleting last keystroke in JTextField if invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836699/deleting-last-keystroke-in-jtextfield-if-invalid/11837028#11837028) and [JTextField limiting character amount input and accepting numeric only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793030/jtextfield-limiting-character-amount-input-and-accepting-numeric-only/12793126#12793126) for examples (especially the links from the answer in the last question)

Answer (score 1):

What will happen if user types a non-numeric character in middle of the text field? Or in beginning?

You can implement a better solution using DocumentFilter:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter

You just need to call super.insert... when you are sure the string being inserted or replaced is valid. (Numeric in your case).

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
        String s = str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length();
```

With your code the value of `s` is always an empty string.

To test if a single character is a digit, use

```
Character.isDigit(str.substring(0,1))
```